# composer: how can a package add a dependency to the project where is used?

Tags: composer-php

### Context

Today I run a `composer update`

Please not, at the end, the locking a package previously removed: `php-http/message-factory`.

The `update` first remove the package `php-http/message-factory`, then *something* add this package as a dependency of *my project* and then re run the composer install process

```
λ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 29 updates, 1 removal
  - Removing php-http/message-factory (v1.0.2)
  - Upgrading carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf (2.1.11 => 2.1.12)
  - Upgrading doctrine/dbal (3.6.1 => 3.6.2)
  - Upgrading fakerphp/faker (v1.21.0 => v1.22.0)
  - Upgrading filp/whoops (2.15.1 => 2.15.2)
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.5.0 => 7.6.1)
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.4.4 => 2.5.0)
  - Upgrading laravelcollective/html (v6.4.0 => v6.4.1)
  - Upgrading mpdf/mpdf (v8.1.5 => v8.1.6)
  - Locking mpdf/psr-log-aware-trait (v2.0.0)
  - Upgrading nyholm/psr7 (1.5.1 => 1.8.0)
  - Upgrading php-http/client-common (2.6.0 => 2.7.0)
  - Upgrading php-http/discovery (1.15.3 => 1.18.0)
  - Upgrading php-http/httplug (2.3.0 => 2.4.0)
  - Upgrading php-http/message (1.13.0 => 1.16.0)
  - Upgrading phpunit/phpunit (9.6.6 => 9.6.8)
  - Upgrading psr/http-client (1.0.1 => 1.0.2)
  - Upgrading psr/http-factory (1.0.1 => 1.0.2)
  - Upgrading psy/psysh (v0.11.14 => v0.11.17)
  - Upgrading sebastian/diff (4.0.4 => 4.0.5)
  - Upgrading sentry/sentry (3.17.0 => 3.18.1)
  - Upgrading shalvah/laravel-jsend (2.3 => 2.4)
  - Upgrading symfony/console (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23)
  - Upgrading symfony/error-handler (v5.4.21 => v5.4.23)
  - Upgrading symfony/http-client (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23)
  - Upgrading symfony/http-foundation (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23)
  - Upgrading symfony/http-kernel (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23)
  - Upgrading symfony/mime (v5.4.21 => v5.4.23)
  - Upgrading symfony/process (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23)
  - Upgrading symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.1.4 => v2.2.0)
  - Upgrading symfony/var-dumper (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 29 updates, 1 removal
  - Downloading php-http/discovery (1.18.0)
  - Downloading symfony/var-dumper (v5.4.23)
  - Downloading symfony/process (v5.4.23)
  - Downloading symfony/mime (v5.4.23)
  - Downloading symfony/http-foundation (v5.4.23)
  - Downloading symfony/error-handler (v5.4.23)
  - Downloading symfony/http-kernel (v5.4.23)
  - Downloading symfony/console (v5.4.23)
  - Downloading mpdf/psr-log-aware-trait (v2.0.0)
  - Downloading mpdf/mpdf (v8.1.6)
  - Downloading carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf (2.1.12)
  - Downloading doctrine/dbal (3.6.2)
  - Downloading fakerphp/faker (v1.22.0)
  - Downloading guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.5.0)
  - Downloading guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.6.1)
  - Downloading psy/psysh (v0.11.17)
  - Downloading filp/whoops (2.15.2)
  - Downloading php-http/message (1.16.0)
  - Downloading php-http/httplug (2.4.0)
  - Downloading php-http/client-common (2.7.0)
  - Downloading sebastian/diff (4.0.5)
  - Downloading phpunit/phpunit (9.6.8)
  - Downloading symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.2.0)
  - Downloading nyholm/psr7 (1.8.0)
  - Downloading symfony/http-client (v5.4.23)
  - Downloading sentry/sentry (3.18.1)
  - Downloading shalvah/laravel-jsend (2.4)
  - Downloading laravelcollective/html (v6.4.1)
  - Removing php-http/message-factory (v1.0.2)
  - Upgrading php-http/discovery (1.15.3 => 1.18.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/var-dumper (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/process (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/mime (v5.4.21 => v5.4.23): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/http-foundation (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/error-handler (v5.4.21 => v5.4.23): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/http-kernel (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/console (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23): Extracting archive
  - Installing mpdf/psr-log-aware-trait (v2.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading mpdf/mpdf (v8.1.5 => v8.1.6): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf (2.1.11 => 2.1.12): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading doctrine/dbal (3.6.1 => 3.6.2): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading fakerphp/faker (v1.21.0 => v1.22.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading psr/http-client (1.0.1 => 1.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading psr/http-factory (1.0.1 => 1.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.4.4 => 2.5.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.5.0 => 7.6.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading psy/psysh (v0.11.14 => v0.11.17): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading filp/whoops (2.15.1 => 2.15.2): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading php-http/message (1.13.0 => 1.16.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading php-http/httplug (2.3.0 => 2.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading php-http/client-common (2.6.0 => 2.7.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading sebastian/diff (4.0.4 => 4.0.5): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading phpunit/phpunit (9.6.6 => 9.6.8): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.1.4 => v2.2.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading nyholm/psr7 (1.5.1 => 1.8.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading symfony/http-client (v5.4.22 => v5.4.23): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading sentry/sentry (3.17.0 => 3.18.1): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading shalvah/laravel-jsend (2.3 => 2.4): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading laravelcollective/html (v6.4.0 => v6.4.1): Extracting archive
Package fruitcake/laravel-cors is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package laravelcollective/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use spatie/laravel-html instead.
Package league/flysystem-sftp is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use league/flysystem-sftp-v3 instead.
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Discovered Package: buzz/laravel-google-captcha
Discovered Package: carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/sail
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: oriceon/toastr-5-laravel
Discovered Package: pragmarx/google2fa-laravel
Discovered Package: sentry/sentry-laravel
Discovered Package: snowfire/beautymail
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-editor
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-fractal
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-html
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
Package manifest generated successfully.
103 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking php-http/message-factory (1.1.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading php-http/message-factory (1.1.0)
  - Installing php-http/message-factory (1.1.0): Extracting archive
Package fruitcake/laravel-cors is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package laravelcollective/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use spatie/laravel-html instead.
Package league/flysystem-sftp is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use league/flysystem-sftp-v3 instead.
Package php-http/message-factory is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/http-factory instead.
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Discovered Package: buzz/laravel-google-captcha
Discovered Package: carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/sail
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: oriceon/toastr-5-laravel
Discovered Package: pragmarx/google2fa-laravel
Discovered Package: sentry/sentry-laravel
Discovered Package: snowfire/beautymail
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-editor
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-fractal
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-html
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
Package manifest generated successfully.
103 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

### Question

What allow a package to add a dependency to *my project* , changing the composer.json of my project during an update?

I ask because could be sometime useful to learn as a php package developer

I never seen this behaviours first, I have no idea of how to instruct composer to add a dependency to the project of the user.

I am looking for documentations, links, or suggestions on how to find which package added this dependency, so I can narrow the search

### Personal investigations

I found a `plugin` in my `composer.json`

```
    "allow-plugins": {
        "php-http/discovery": true
    }
```

I never find the concept of composer plugin before. And this is interesting

I am examining the source code of this plugin

Comment: `php artisan package:discover --ansi` is the command that is called, and it seems to require that package. That does not look like a core Composer feature, but any Laravel feature

Comment: But how can a package create a new dependency in a project of mine!? (and why vote to close this question ... but it's useless ... so community is so rude ...)

Comment: "how can a package create a new dependency in a project of mine" - it's not a package that creates a new dependency, but any command that you are using in your `composer.json`. It can safely run whatever forked command it wants to run, and in your case it seems to run `composer require`

Comment: See my answer. It is really a package that is able to change the files using postUpdate hooks. After running a composer update, never before I seen composer.json changed. First time. Now I know the source and the way. But are indirect behaviour, due to plugin package code, and not related to my commands !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a `plugin` in my `composer.json`

```
    "allow-plugins": {
        "php-http/discovery": true
    }
```

I never find the concept of composer plugin before. And this is interesting

I am examining the source code of this plugin

A lot of interesting technics used here

If you are interested to deep into, you can read source code here

https://github.com/php-http/discovery/blob/1.x/src/Composer/Plugin.php

It registers some hooks into composer install/update flow so he can change the composer.json itself. See [this portion of code](https://github.com/php-http/discovery/blob/1.x/src/Composer/Plugin.php#L124-L130).